# How to stop the clone via gitBash in the middle of a clone time?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I want to stop the clone.

The cloning process is in mid of 26% but i want to stop the process. what is the command?

Answer (score 2):

You should simply press `CTRL-C`.

Comment: The answer is right, but less than explanatory, if I may ^^ Let's at least mention that it stops the current running bash process, it's not a git mechanism. It implies that it won't shut down cleanly, you'll have to delete the unfinished clone yourself.

Comment: You are right, sorry!